# Do TCP connections work differently within the same subnet?

Tags: networking, tcp

I've encountered some network behaviour that confuses me while trying to get Java RMI working.

I use netcat to connect to a local machine:

```
[my_machine]$ nc -w 1 192.168.0.100 60000 && echo success
success
```

I try to do the same to my server:

```
[my_machine]$ nc -w 1 my-servers-ip 60000 && echo success
```

This doesn't work, unless I explicitly listen on the server socket:

```
[amazon_ec2]$ nc -l 60000 

[my_machine]$ nc -w 1 my-servers-ip 60000 && echo success
success
```

For the version that fails, the `SYN` packet receives a `RST, ACK` in response.

I'm not too knowledgable about this stuff, at this point I only have wild theories such as the one in the question. Any ideas?

Potentially useful details:

```
Local Machine (192.168.0.100) - Macbook

Remote Machine (Amazon EC2) - Amazon Linux AMI 2012.03 
    Security Group Settings:
        22 (SSH)        0.0.0.0/0
        1099            0.0.0.0/0
        49152-65535     0.0.0.0/0
    "iptables -L" shows no rules set
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, TCP connections work the same way for local or remote (routed) servers. The three-way handshake is the same.

You can check

- some service is actially listening on port 60000 (`netstat`)
- the service is not configured to reject non-local clients in some way
- no firewall is blocking traffic

Comment: And this is why we go to bed and try again in the morning. Thanks.